# A famous shift from vouvoiement to tutoiement in an 18th- or 19th-century French play

Tags: littérature, vouvoiement, tutoiement

I'm trying to remember the 18th- or 19th-century play in which two men *vouvoient* one another, but then suddenly one shifts to the shock of the other man (and the audience). It goes something like this:

> Homme 1 : (some statement or question with *vous*)
> Homme 2 : Moi ?
> Homme 1 : Toi.

I thought it was Corneille's *Le Cid* but I've looked through the text and can't find it. So then I turned to ChatGPT which just straight up invented scenes from several different plays (including *Le Cid*, funnily enough) and apologized when I called it on it, and then gave up. (*Je m'excuse pour la confusion. Je ne suis pas sûr de quelle pièce de théâtre vous parlez.)*

I just can't figure it out. Anyone know?

Comment: Hmm... that's not a lot to go on. There are probably a few such instances. I remember there's a scene in Les Mis where Javert switches from vous to tu with Valjean when he comes to the point of recognizing him...

Comment: *Le Cid* is 17th century. Are you looking for a tragedy? In classical comedy, it is very frequent to switch from vouvoiement to tutoiement in fight scenes when characters call each other names.

Comment: Yes, it was a tragedy. I just remember reading this scene in class and discussing how the switch from vous to tu was so shocking. It definitely wasn't a fight scene - it was a discussion or maybe an argument. I'm interested in this one in particular because it was so succinct.

Comment: Si ton souvenir de « tragédie » est fiable, la mention de tutoiement et vouvoiement fait penser à l'Acte IV, scène 5 d'*Andromaque* (Racine)  où Hermione, s'adressant à Pyrrhus passe du tutoiement au vouvoiement pour revenir au tutoiement ; passage qui est étudié pour  montrer la fluctuation des sentiments d'Hermione à travers l'utilisation du vouvoiement et du tutoiement. But your use of "so shocking" doesn't fit when describing this use of *tu* and *vous* (at least for French natives) by Hermione. [The text](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1177772d/f189.item) of the play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En effet, il s'agit du *Cid* de Corneille, acte I, scène 3. Don Diègue et le Comte (Don Gomès) se disputent. À un moment donné, Don Diègue met le Comte en colère, ce qui entraîne le passage au tutoiement et finit par une gifle du Comte à Don Diègue:

> Le Comte 
> Parlons-en mieux, le Roi fait honneur à votre âge. 
>  
> Don Diègue 
> Le Roi, quand il en fait, le mesure au courage. 
> Le Comte 
> Et par là cet honneur n’était dû qu’à mon bras. 
>  
> Don Diègue 
> Qui n’a pu l’obtenir ne le méritait pas. 
> Le Comte 
> Ne le méritait pas! moi? 
> Don Diègue 
> Vous. 
> Le Comte  
> Ton impudence, 
> Téméraire vieillard, aura sa récompense.
> (Il lui donne un soufflet.)