# Is there a term for fluctuating between vouvoiement and tutoiement in literature / film?

Tags: vocabulaire, littérature, cinéma, vouvoiement, tutoiement

In literature, movies, and TV, it's very common for speakers to switch betwen *vouvoiement* and *tutoiement* in order to show (or hide) changing relationships. For example, disrespect during an [argument in *Le Cid*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52790/a-famous-shift-from-vouvoiement-to-tutoiement-in-an-18th-or-19th-century-french), or how two people might continue using *vous* in public to hide the fact that they're in an intimate relationship.

Is there a term for this sort of switching?

Or would you just say something like *Ils changent entre le vouvoiement et le tutoiement / Ils continuent à se vouvoyer en public tout en se tutoyant chez eux*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

À ma connaissance il n'y a pas de mot spécifique. La façon la plus habituelle que je connaisse est de dire qu'**on passe du tutoiement au vouvoiement**. Ainsi je dirais que, dans *Une vie*, Maupassant fait passer Julien du vouvoiement au tutoiement juste après la nuit de noces de façon à faire ressortir sa vulgarité verbale envers Jeanne<sup>1</sup>.

Quelques exemples glanés ça et là :

> je me dis qu'à présent que nous sommes amis ... je pourrais passer au tutoiement<sup>2</sup> !

> La décision a été prise, après concertation avec la directrice technique, de passer du tutoiement au vouvoiement une seule fois entre Anna et son époux<sup>3</sup> ,...

> Et Emma, piquée au vif, passant du tutoiement au vouvoiement pour mieux montrer son désagrément, de rétorquer aussitôt<sup>4</sup> ...

> Le Comte, lui, peut passer du tutoiement au vouvoiement, ou vice-versa, comme dans la scène 9 du troisième acte, où il parle avec Suzanne. ll la vouvoie, au début, non par respect, mais parce qu'il est en colère et veut ainsi marquer la distance<sup>5</sup>.

Pour indiquer les va-et-vient plutôt que d'utiliser « ou vice versa » comme dans l'exemple ci-dessus, je pense qu'il est plus courant de dire « alterner entre ».

> La tendance, pour certains enquêtés, à alterner entre le vouvoiement et le tutoiement à mesure que le temps passe est à cet égard révélatrice<sup>6</sup>...

> Évitez, dans la mesure du possible, d'alterner le tutoiement et le vouvoiement, sans réellement choisir<sup>7</sup>.

On peut utiliser divers verbes de mouvement pour faire ressortir un élément psychologique ou créer un effet de style : *hésiter/naviguer/fluctuer.. entre...*

---

<sup>1. Le vouvoiement entre époux était courant au 19e s.</sup>
<sup>2. Sur [un forum](https://www.thebikets.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=410&start=40).</sup> 
<sup>3. [La traduction audiovisuelle : contraintes (et) pratiques](https://journals.openedition.org/decadrages/695?lang=en).</sup> 
<sup>4. [Les filles du calvaire,](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_filles_du_calvaire/dPOw_wk7YwwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%20du%20tutoiement%20au%20vouvoiement%22&pg=PT192&printsec=frontcover)Pierre Combescot· 2007</sup>
<sup>5. Dans [une étude scolaire](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Profil_Beaumarchais_Le_Mariage_de_Figaro/imKzDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=Le%20Comte,%20lui,%20peut%20passer%20du%20tutoiement%20au%20vouvoiement,%20ou%20vice-versa,%20comme%20dans%20la%20sc%C3%A8ne%209%20du%20troisi%C3%A8me%20acte,%20o%C3%B9%20il%20parle%20avec%20Suzanne.%20ll%20la%20vouvoie,%20au%20d%C3%A9but,%20non%20par%20respect,%20mais%20parce%20quil%20est%20en%20col%C3%A8re%20et%20veut%20ainsi%20marquer%20la%20distance&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover) sur le *Mariage de Figaro* de Beaumarchais.</sup>  
<sup>6. « [La relation aux enquêtés et l’accumulation des données au fil du temps](https://books.openedition.org/pur/145517?lang=fr) », in *Comprendre le social dans la durée*</sup>  
<sup>7. [Gérer les conflits au collège et au lycée](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/G%C3%A9rer_les_conflits_au_coll%C3%A8ge_et_au_ly/g02J5d5ySpkC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=alterne%20entre%20le%20tutoiement%20et%20le%20%20vouvoiement&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover), Laurent Le Bars· 2012.</sup>